# Is there any way to extract a value from particular cell and store it in another spreadsheet cell(everyday @midnight 12) using spreadsheet Appsscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I'm aware that I can extract a cell entry at mentioned timestamp and send the value to my mail id like below.

```
function triggerMail() {
  // Fetch the monthly sales
  var toGoRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NetWorth").getRange("H741"); 
  var toGo = toGoRange.getValue();
  // Fetch the email address
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NetWorth").getRange("J2");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5.30", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  // Send Alert Email.
  var message = '[' + date + ']' + ' Still toGo Rs.' + Number((toGo).toFixed(2)) + ' this month'; // Second column
  var subject = 'Daily ToGo Report';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    
};
```

Is there any way to store the value of **toGo** in the spreadsheet cell?.
So that I can get an entry in the spreadsheet every day (currently, I'm getting an email every day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the value to the sheet using [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).

For example, if you want to write to cell A1, you can add this to the end of your function (possibly instead of the line that sends the email): `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NetWorth").getRange('A1').setValue(toGo);`

---

Edit:

If you want to keep a log of a value each time the function is run, you can write it to the [last row of a given column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26062012/3751868). For example, to log it to column A:

```
function logToGo() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NetWorth");
  const toGo = sheet.getRange("H741").getValue();

  // Find the last populated row in the specified column
  const logColumn = 1; // Number of the column to output "toGo" to. A is 1, B is 2, etc.
  let logColumnLastRow = sheet.getMaxRows();
  const data = sheet.getRange(1, logColumn, logColumnLastRow).getValues();
  while (data[logColumnLastRow - 1][0] === "" && logColumnLastRow > 0) {
    logColumnLastRow--;
  }

  // Write to the last row in the specified column
  sheet.getRange(logColumnLastRow+1, logColumn).setValue(toGo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but is there any way to keep a record of it?. Here, I see it overrides A1 in the next day.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer to write the value to a different row every time the function runs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `setValue()` ([link to google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)).

So after your 4th line, use something like this:

```
var enterRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ENTER SHEET NAME").getRange("ENTER RANGE").setValue(toGo);
```

If you want to enter it in a different SpreadSheet altogether, use the following:

```
var enterRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ENTER SPREADSHEET ID").getSheetByName("ENTER SHEET NAME").getRange("ENTER RANGE").setValue(toGo);
```

If you don't know, how to find the spreadsheet id, here is a [red arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X9wr.png) pointing to it.